# What happens if you return a reference to a local variable through a lambda function object?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, reference

```
#include <iostream>

auto get_lambda()
{
    int i = 5;
    auto lambda = [&i]() { std::cout << i << '\n'; };
    return lambda;
}

int main()
{
    auto lambda = get_lambda();
    lambda();
}
```

Inside the 'get_lambda' function I define the local variable 'i'.
The function then returns the lambda object that has one capture reference to that local variable.
Inside 'main', I call that lambda, and 'i' turns out to be uninitialized memory.

The variable 'i' is located on the stack of get_lambda. This stack is no longer valid when the function returns.

Why does this code even compile and what exactly happens to the variable 'i', is it still useable outside of get_lambda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you are invoking [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). The `i` name is local to `get_lambda()` function, and once `i` gets out of scope, it gets destroyed. So, with your lambda, you are now storing a reference to something that isn't there anymore. This is also known as a *dangling reference*. Capture the local variable by value instead:

```
auto lambda = [i]() { std::cout << i << '\n'; };
```

or:

```
auto lambda = [=]() { std::cout << i << '\n'; };
```

You are indeed allowed to capture locals by reference in the lambda's capture-list. Hence, no compiler error. Depending on the compiler, a warning might be issued.

Comment: I know that a capture by value, would avoid this problem.
I know from C that a pointer to a local variable, in a function, that has already returned, is an dangling pointer.
But I'm amazed that this is also possible with references.
I know dangling pointers, but dangling references are new to me.

Comment: @PaulSanders that is an *implementation detail*.  It is *common* for a compiler to implement a reference using a pointer internally, but that is not required by the standard, and not all implementations actually do that.

Answer (score 3):

`i` is only available in its scope, which is inside `get_lambda()`. Obviously it is not usable outside its scope, which is what you are attempting when calling `lambda()` later.

Just like using a dangling pointer, this is undefined behavior. Similarly, the compiler will let you "use" such a pointer, but it's your duty as a programmer to know that you are breaking a rule.

Comment: Inside the lambda function body, it's possible to set `i` to any value and also read it.
So it is useable, but I think it's a dangling pointer, as you say.
I think `i` is located below the stack pointer and therefore get used by other functions, that are later called in `main`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Inside the lambda function body, it's possible to set i to any value and also read it. So it is useable". The only way things are usable there, is if you call `lambda()` inside `get_lambda()`, otherwise it will blow up as `i` no longer exists.

Comment: If I replace this `{ std::cout << i << '\n'; };` lambda function body by this `{ i = 4; std::cout << i << '\n'; };`, it will still work without any warnings.
I use Visual Studio 2019 16.5.4

Comment: Right, still undefined behavior, as in "anything is allowed to happen". And very important when data is corrupted, "if you’re very unlucky, the program will do exactly what you hoped it should do, until you change some unrelated code / compiler versions / compiler vendors / operating systems / hardware platforms – and then a new bug becomes visible, and you have no clue why seemingly correct code now fails to work properly". See this very nice [introduction](https://www.nayuki.io/page/undefined-behavior-in-c-and-cplusplus-programs#introduction).