# Variable lifetimes in scopes

Tags: c++

I'm implementing a CLI parser using [CLI11](https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11), and I want to use nested scope braces to enable me to

- not being able to accidentally interact with other subcommands, and
- use and re-use variable names locally, without worrying about name clashes.

To that end I have the following structure:

```
#include <CLI11.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    CLI::App app;

    {
        CLI::App* task = app.add_subcommand("task");
        {
            int id{0};
            CLI::App* start = task->add_subcommand("start");
            start->add_option("id", id);
            start->callback([&id] { std::cout << "task start " << id << std::endl; });
        }
    }

    CLI11_PARSE(app, argc, argv);

    return 0;
}
```

Now my question is: what happens to the variable `id` here? Does it get dropped when I leave the innermost scope? I've passed it to `add_option()` and to the lambda in `callback()`, will these functions be able to use them later, e.g. when the lambda is executed later?

Right now the code compiles and runs correctly, but I am not sure if that's just 'accidentally fine'.

Comment: The lifetime of a variable ends with the scope it's defined in. So yes, once the innermost `}` is reached, the variable `id` ceases to exist.

Comment: I am surprised that this example "appears to work", that is, it always prints correct number, and valgrind doesn't detect any invalid reads/writes.

Comment: [What happens if you return a reference to a local variable through a lambda function object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61739490/what-happens-if-you-return-a-reference-to-a-local-variable-through-a-lambda-func) and [Lambdas and capture by reference local variables : Accessing after the scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775233/lambdas-and-capture-by-reference-local-variables-accessing-after-the-scope)

Answer (score 3):

Using captured-by-reference variable, that went out-of scope, inside your lambda is Undefined Behavior. Unfortunately, there is no magic in CLI parser that will make it work. Compiling your code with

```
-fsanitize=address
```

and running with

```
./foo task start 12345
```

I managed to get an error from address sanitizer:

```
==68918==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope on address 0x7fffdfbbfa00
(...)
Address 0x7fffdfbbfa00 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 176 in frame
    #0 0x560994d243df in main /home/pptaszni/workspace/FooBar/src/main.cpp:4

  This frame has 32 object(s):
    [32, 33) '<unknown>'
    (...)
    [176, 180) 'id' (line 9) <== Memory access at offset 176 is inside this variable
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/n5hndY1ve vs https://godbolt.org/z/Kdb891a6Y

Comment: O, thx @MarekR , I also tried to use godbolt, but the compiler kept getting "Killed - processing time exceeded".

Comment: got similar issue. I've reduced optimization level then it passed.