# lambda reference capturing leads to unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, lambda, lifetime

So I was trying to get my feet wet with `asio` library. But am baffled by the following lambda capture mystery.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <asio/include/asio.hpp>

void handler1( const asio::error_code& ec, asio::steady_timer& t, int count ) {
    if( count < 5  ) {
        std::cout << "I have waited " << count << " seconds\n";
        t.expires_at( t.expiry() + asio::chrono::seconds( 1 ) );
        // auto next_count = count + 1;
        t.async_wait( [&t, &count]( const asio::error_code& ec ) {
            handler1( ec, t, count + 1 );
        });
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    asio::io_context io_context;
    asio::steady_timer t ( io_context, asio::chrono::seconds( 1 ) );
    t.async_wait( [&t]( const asio::error_code& ec ) {
                handler1( ec, t, 0 );
            }
     );

    io_context.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Problem happens on the `&count` lambda capture in the `handler1` function. This code will produce the following on my Mac:

(Apple Clang++ 15.0.0)

```
I have waited 0 seconds
I have waited 2 seconds
I have waited 2 seconds
... ...
```

(g++ 13.2.0)

```
I have waited 0 seconds
I have waited 1 seconds
I have waited 1 seconds
... ...
```

**If the `&count` capture is changed to `count`, which is capture by copy, it produces expected behavior**
(g++ 13.2.0)

```
I have waited 0 seconds
I have waited 1 seconds
I have waited 2 seconds
I have waited 3 seconds
... ...
```

So what is going on. I am pretty sure the function `handler1` captures `count` by copy, so I don't think there will be any difference between capturing the `count` by reference or value in  the lambda capture.

Comment: `count` is a local variable, so you cannot store it's address and then use it after the function returns. This applies for capture by reference. When you capture by copy, you're making a copy and so it works as expected. See [What happens if you return a reference to a local variable through a lambda function object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61739490/12002570) and also [Lambdas and capture by reference local variables : Accessing after the scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775233/lambdas-and-capture-by-reference-local-variables-accessing-after-the-scope)

Comment: `handler1` doesn't "capture" anything.

Comment: @user12002570 Can you elaborate on the 'return' part you are mentioning? I don't see the return, sorry..

Comment: @cxz Basically, capturing by reference to a local variable and then using that will only be valid until the reference itslef is valid(meaning the local variable has not gone out of scope). In other words, accessing local variable out of their scope is invalid.

Comment: @user12002570 Yeah that's true, so in my case, I capture the count in the lambda by references, that's good? if it's good, the count + 1 gets copied into the nested handler1 local stack. So where is the problem ?

Comment: @user12002570 Can you tell when count goes out of scope specifically ? much appreciation.

Comment: @cxz Whenever you use that lambda that stored the reference to `count` will be UB. Also, `count` is created each time you call `handler1` and goes out of scope at the end of its body. So, if/when you use the lambda after `handler1` has been completely executed, you'll have UB.

Comment: @user12002570 where did I use the lambda after handler1? Sorry that’s not obvious to me. I know what you are saying. I can’t use a lambda that has a reference to a local variable when the stack has been destroyed. But it’s not obvious in my case right? Note the handler1 call is nested, the outer handler1 stack is never destructed.

Comment: @user12002570 OMG it’s asynchronous wait, so the outer handler1 is destructed.

Comment: @user12002570 is that right?